# Renewing an API token in an ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm calling into a 3rd party API from my ASP.NET MVC app. This API uses a service/API token that you get by calling a "renew" API.  It expires after 5 days.

If you call one of the service's APIs and the token as expired, you get an "api token expired" error and you can call the renew function.

I don't want to do this because it complicates my code by having to always check for the "api token expired" error and have the logic to retry.  I'd rather just make sure the renew function gets called "relatively frequently but not on every request".

I do not want to use a timer or chron solution if I can avoid it.

I thought I read somewhere that IIS7+ automatically by default recycles the application instances on a regular basis. If this default is less than 5 days then I can just use Application_Start.

Comment: I would rather not rely on IIS settings because those can be changed by admins as per rules/policies. Why don't you store the token in the database and have windows service that renews the token every 5 days? That would be safe and would work 100% of the times.

Comment: @Suhas - yes you are right that settings can be changed by server admins, but I can't envision a case where application would not be recycled for 5 days in a row. Is that even possible?.. I believe Application_Start is relatively safe and suitable place for this logic to take place.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `Application_Start` and check that it has been at least `x` time since the last time you renewed the token, perhaps by storing a `DateTime` of when the last token was retrieved in a database or file.

You shouldn't have the app automatically starting up just for this.

(my advice would be to use the API in the way it is supposed to be used; you might run into a problem with the API provider if you request it too often, for example.)